# How to use pronouns correctly?

Tags: pronouns

Choose the correct pronoun to complete the sentence.

> No other boy in our neighborhood runs as fast as (he, him).

Choose the correct pronoun to complete the sentence.

> Who could make spaghetti better than (she, her)?

Choose the correct pronoun to complete the sentence.

> The book about the history of pencils was more interesting to you than to (he, him).

Comment: Unless you are more pedantic than me, both answers are correct for the first two questions.

Comment: This is not a homework (etc)-answering service. However, I will point out that the answer you get here will almost certainly be different from the one your teacher wants. Refer him/her to [Geoff Pullum's article](http://news.ucsc.edu/2002/04/107.html) (Myth 5). And Geoff Pullum is the nearest thing to a final arbiter on English usage most people accept.

Answer (score 3):

The simple rule is that one may always use the objective pronoun (*him, me, her*)
instead of the subjective one (*he, I, she*) ...

> **Unless** the pronoun in question is the subject of a verb that is in the sentence.

In the first 2 examples, there is no verb, so the objective pronoun is allowed.
But there **is** an understood verb, and one may also use the subjective pronoun
to refer to that, in more formal language, mostly written. In speech, it would be rare.

In the last example, there is a preposition *to*, and the pronoun is its object.
That requires the objective form, and disallows the subjective, because there's no verb.

Answer (score 2):

"He's already got more hair than me, thank God."
MRH Prince William in re HRH Prince George.  Unaccountably, 'tis the King's English.

Comment: Isn't this treason? Or have I missed some important news?

Comment: Under the Treaty of Ghent I am a non-subject.